# AWS IAM - What damage can be done using access and secret access key with no permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

What damage can be done using an IAM user (with access key and secret access key) if there are no permissions attached to this user and this user's console login is disabled as well ?

Is it like people would be able to authenticate with aws using cli/sdk but won't be able to perform any actions (access any resources) as there are no permissions/roles are given to this user or there is something else to it ?

Comment: If a bucket exists in the same account that grants that user permissions then the user can do stuff with the bucket, same with any other resource that offer some kind of resource policy.

Comment: So that user won't be able to access anything on its own but can access any resource with resource permissions which say that resource is accessible to anyone within the account , correct ?

Comment: @user10916892 Yep. The resource doesn't need to be accessible to anyone. The resource could have a resource policy which targets this particular IAM user.